# Наложение изображения поверх другого в div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы при нажатии на ячейку `div`, должно появиться меню с различными спрайтами, и при нажатии на соответствующий спрайт, данный спрайт должен наложиться поверх старого спрайта. В качестве спрайтов я использую обычные png-изображения размером 32x32.

---

Более подробное объяснение проблемы:

Я создаю так называемый "редактор", в котором, пользователь сможет при нажатии на ячейку, выбрать соответствующий спрайт, и тем самым, создавать различные объекты на сцене. Сцена выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта сцена представляет собой матрицу ячеек 24x30.

Данные ячейки я создаю следующим образом:

```html
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y1"   onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y2"   onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y3"   onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="divTableCell" id="x24y30" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css :

```css
.divTable{
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

и заполняю я их спрайтами по умолчанию (травой) при помощи js функции:

```js
function addDefaultSprites() {

    for (let x = 1; x < 25; x++) {
        for (let y = 1; y < 31; y++) {
            var id = document.getElementById('x' + x + 'y' + y);
            id.style.backgroundImage = "url(static/img/sprites/tile_01.png)";
            id.style.backgroundSize  = "32px";
        }
    }
}
```

Полный код выглядит так:

```css
.parent {
    max-width       : 1600px;
    min-width       : 1600px;
    min-height      : 900px;
    max-height      : 900px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin          : auto;
    position        : relative;
}

.child {

    background-color: #a80000;
    max-width       : 1400px;
    min-width       : 1400px;
    min-height      : 806px;
    max-height      : 806px;
    padding         : 20px;
    position        : absolute;
    top             : 100px;
    left            : 100px;
}

.divTable{
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.divTableCell:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
   
</head>
<body>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y1" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y2" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y3" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y4" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y5" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y6" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y7" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y8" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y9" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y10" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y11" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y12" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y13" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y14" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y15" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y16" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y17" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y18" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y19" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y20" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y21" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y22" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y23" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y24" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y25" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y26" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y27" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y28" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y29" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y30" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
                    И так далее ...
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script>

    function createSprite(id) {
      // ignore
    }
    
    function addDefaultSprites() {

        for (let x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
            for (let y = 1; y < 31; y++) {
                var id = document.getElementById('x' + x + 'y' + y);
                id.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.ibb.co/7vCSkqS/tile-01.png)";
                id.style.backgroundSize = "32px";
            }
        }
    }
    addDefaultSprites();

</script>
</html>
```

И тут появляется самая главная проблема. Как мне добавить новый спрайт поверх старого, и чтобы пропорции таблицы не поменялись. Мне не проблема создать функционал добавления (вывод меню, и так далее), моя проблема в том, что я понятия не имею, как добавить новое изображение поверх существующего. Например, я хочу создать что-то подобное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данном примере, мы видим, что добавленный спрайт телевизора находиться над спрайтом стола.

Спрайт телевизора: [image: введите сюда описание изображения], и спрайт стола: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это похоже на `photoshop`, где мы создаем новые слои изображений и накладываем их поверх других.

Comment: может попробовать сделать что то вроде: для первого положенного спрайта `z-index` равен 1, для второго 2 и т.д.? я пытаюсь гадать поскольку не знаю какие детали у вас устроены

Comment: Я тоже думал о z-индексе, но тогда, в моем случае, мне нужно будет переделать код, а именно вставить тег `img` в `div`.

Comment: @bbdd Значит самое время переделать код) У блока может быть несколько `background-image: url(img-1.png), url(img-2.png);` через запятую. Но это значит много предстоящей работы со строками. Легче сделать position: relative / absolute квадратики, куда будут добавляться абсолютные блоки с единственным background-image. Которые естественным образом будут складываться друг на друга.

Comment: Может вам стоит менять class у указанyого div? То есть позиции хранить в id а их состояния в class / Тогда это поможет с этим элементом удобнее работать в будущем . А уже в зависимости от значения className  менять вид

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоватся не наложением, а заменой изображения, вот так:

```js
    function createSprite(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iggwJ.png)";
    }
    
    function addDefaultSprites() {

        for (let x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
            for (let y = 1; y < 31; y++) {
                var id = document.getElementById('x' + x + 'y' + y);
                id.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.ibb.co/7vCSkqS/tile-01.png)";
                id.style.backgroundSize = "32px";
            }
        }
    }
    addDefaultSprites();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.parent {
    /*max-width       : 1600px;*/
    /*min-width       : 1600px;*/
    /*min-height      : 900px;*/
    /*max-height      : 900px;*/
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin          : auto;
    position        : relative;
}

.child {
    background-color: #a80000;
    max-width       : 1000px;
    min-width       : 1000px;
    min-height      : 806px;
    max-height      : 806px;
    padding         : 20px;
    /*position        : absolute;*/
    /*top             : 100px;*/
    /*left            : 100px;*/
}

.divTable{
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.divTableCell:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y1" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y2" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y3" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y4" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y5" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y6" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y7" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y8" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y9" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y10" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y11" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y12" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y13" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y14" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y15" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y16" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y17" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y18" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y19" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y20" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y21" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y22" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y23" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y24" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y25" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y26" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y27" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y28" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y29" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y30" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
                    И так далее ...
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

А если изменять разные спрайты одним кликом, то можно воспользоватся вот такой идеей, использовать имя элемента для обозначения типа спрайта:

```js
function createSprite(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element.getAttribute('name') == "0"){
          element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iggwJ.png)";
          element.setAttribute('name', '1');
        } else if (element.getAttribute('name') == "1") {
          element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u8FX.png)";
          element.setAttribute('name', '2');
        } else {
          element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.ibb.co/7vCSkqS/tile-01.png)";
          element.setAttribute('name', '0');
        }
    }
    
    function addDefaultSprites() {

        for (let x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
            for (let y = 1; y < 31; y++) {
                var id = document.getElementById('x' + x + 'y' + y);
                id.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.ibb.co/7vCSkqS/tile-01.png)";
                id.style.backgroundSize = "32px";
            }
        }
    }
    addDefaultSprites();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.parent {
    /*max-width       : 1600px;*/
    /*min-width       : 1600px;*/
    /*min-height      : 900px;*/
    /*max-height      : 900px;*/
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin          : auto;
    position        : relative;
}

.child {
    background-color: #a80000;
    max-width       : 1000px;
    min-width       : 1000px;
    min-height      : 806px;
    max-height      : 806px;
    padding         : 20px;
    /*position        : absolute;*/
    /*top             : 100px;*/
    /*left            : 100px;*/
}

.divTable{
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.divTableCell:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #EEE;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="divTable">
                <div class="divTableBody">
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y1" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y2" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y3" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y4" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y5" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y6" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y7" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y8" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y9" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y10" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y11" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y12" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y13" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y14" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y15" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y16" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y17" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y18" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y19" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y20" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y21" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y22" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y23" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y24" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y25" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y26" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y27" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y28" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y29" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="divTableCell" id="x1y30" name="0" onclick="createSprite(id)">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
                    И так далее ...
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```